# Метод std::getline вызывает ошибку "нарушение прав доступа при чтении". ПРИ ПЕРЕДАЧЕ string msg в него

Tags: c++, c, строки, std, getline

**ClientS.cpp**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

SOCKET Connection;

enum SocketPackage {
    P_Message
};

bool ProcessPackage(SocketPackage package) {
    switch (package)
    {
        case P_Message:
        {
            int alias_size, msg_size;
            recv(Connection, (char*)&alias_size, sizeof(alias_size), NULL);
            recv(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(msg_size), NULL);

            char* alias = new char[alias_size + 1];
            char* msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
            alias[alias_size] = '\0';
            msg[msg_size] = '\0';

            recv(Connection, (char*)&alias, alias_size, NULL);
            recv(Connection, (char*)&msg, msg_size, NULL);

            std::cout << "[" << alias << "] " << msg << std::endl;
            delete[] alias, msg;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            std::cout << "Unregistred package: " << package << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void ClientHandler() {
    SocketPackage package;
    while (true) {
        recv(Connection, (char*)&package, sizeof(package), NULL);

        if (!ProcessPackage(package)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Connection);
}

int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) {
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string alias;
    std::getline(std::cin, alias);
    int alias_size = alias.size();

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(43579);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error: failed connect to server.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandler, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    std::string msg;
    while (true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, msg);  // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫБРАСЫВАЕТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
        int msg_size = msg.size();
        
        SocketPackage package = P_Message;

        send(Connection, (char*)&package, sizeof(package), NULL);
        send(Connection, (char*)&alias_size, sizeof(alias_size), NULL);
        send(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(msg_size), NULL);
        send(Connection, alias.c_str(), alias_size, NULL);
        send(Connection, msg.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот здесь ошибка:

```
        std::string msg;
        while (true) {
            std::getline(std::cin, msg);  // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫБРАСЫВАЕТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
            int msg_size = msg.size();
```

Comment: Тут на каждом шагу ошибки - при создании потока, при чтении и записи в сокеты, использование с-style кастов.

Comment: можно по-подробнее?

Answer (score 1):

```
recv(Connection, (char*)&alias, alias_size, NULL);
recv(Connection, (char*)&msg, msg_size, NULL);
```

Должно быть:

```
recv(Connection, alias, alias_size, NULL);
recv(Connection, msg, msg_size, NULL);
```

У вас портится память, поэтому программа может упасть в любом месте.